# Echo SUM from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum, echo

```
<?php $q = $this->db->query("select SUM(pocet_dni) as pocet from holiday where teacher_id="._get_current_user_id($this));
                                 $pocet_dni = $row['pocet'];
                                    echo $pocet;
               ?>
```

I can not echo SUM. What is wrong?

Comment: You need group by caluse to sum.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I checked the sql code it's work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$pocet` does not exists. Use `row_array()`.

```
$q = $this->db->query("select SUM(pocet_dni) as pocet from holiday where teacher_id="._get_current_user_id($this))->row_array();
$pocet = $q['pocet'];
echo $pocet;
```